# Javascript Questions issues

Tags: javascript, dom

Hey guys so Im making a customer name textfield and have these requirements.

get how many chars are in name

check if name is greater than 6 if so then continue to next check

check if 1st char is a space then fail

if last char is space then fail

must have a space somewhere in name

This is what I have done so far, it does not work so I know its syntax could someone help me? I also cannot do the must have a space part, I assume Il have to loop through the name and check if the current char is a space each time and if so add to a variable and then at end check if variable is above 0?

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    var NamePass = true;

    function ValidateName()
    {
        var BlankPass = true;
        var GreaterThan6Pass = true;
        var FirstBlankPass = true;

        if (document.getElementById('Name').value=="")
        {
            document.getElementById('Name').style.background="red";
            BlankPass = false;
        }

        var Size = document.getElementById('Name').value.lastIndexOf();
        if (Size>7)
        {
            document.getElementById('Name').style.background="red";
            GreaterThan6Pass = false;
        }

        if (document.getElementById('Name').value.(str.substring(0,1)==" ")
        {
            document.getElementById('Name').style.background="red";
            FirstBlankPass = false;
        }

        var LastIndex = document.getElementById('Name').value.lastIndexOf();
        if (document.getElementById('Name').value.(str.substring((LastIndex-1),1)==" ")
        {
            document.getElementById('Name').style.background="red";
            FirstBlankPass = false;
        }   

        if (BlankPass == false || GreaterThan6Pass == false || FirstBlankPass == false )
        {
            NamePass = false;
        }
    }
</script>
<body>

<b>Customer Information</b><br>
<dd>Your name: 
<input type=text name="Name" size=40 maxlength=40 id="Name"     onblur="ValidateName()">
<img id="NameTick" style="width: 15; height: 15;     visibility:hidden;" src="Tick.png" />
<br>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**jsFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/UTtxA/1/)

---

You seem to have a few syntax errors, namely:

```
if (document.getElementById('Name').value.(str.substring(0,1)==" ")
```

should be:

```
if (document.getElementById('Name').value.substring(0,1) == " ")
```

and

```
if (document.getElementById('Name').value.(str.substring((LastIndex-1),1)==" ")
```

should be:

```
if (document.getElementById('Name').value.substring((LastIndex-1),1) == " ")
```

---

**Edit:**

In regard to your comments, I've went through your code and changed all your logic to make it work as you wish, it's a little too much code to put here so I'll just leave the [**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/UTtxA/8/) for you instead.

Comment: Thanks also found that it should have been Size<7, great tool im using it from now on!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/UTtxA/1/
Can you help solve this and il tick your answer :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/UTtxA/3/ ;D forgot to save

Comment: the part where it should have a space in the name. Like 'hdhdhdhdh ddh' should work while 'gndhbggbgfgfgb' should not

Comment: @Steven Your logic is flawed in this code, if the length > 7, then one of the flags is true so it will never turn red, even with a space. See here - http://jsfiddle.net/UTtxA/5/. Make sure you have Firebug/Chrome tools open so you can read the console.log values I've set.

Comment: ahh I see, should I do that check as an if then if so do the others in the if?

Comment: @Steven Even if you do that, your `BlankMiddleName` section does not work. `BlankPass`, `GreaterThan6Pass` and `FirstBlankPass` do work.

Comment: is there anyway to do this? Its difficult for a beginner :)

Comment: Your right, just hate not being able to finish the section, right answer :)

Comment: Still does not work owell :) 'batagga ah' for example goes red

Comment: Hmm if you type 'hhhhhhhhhhh' then type 'hhhhhhhhhhhh ggggg' it does not go white :/

Comment: @Steven That's because you didn't tell it to - http://jsfiddle.net/UTtxA/9/

Comment: Thanks got this much working, last thing is it does not go red if there is a space at the end of the name? http://jsfiddle.net/UTtxA/10/

Answer (score 0):

The way you're doing it is really complicated, you should use a regex instead.

See http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp for how regexes work

Your regex would look like this for a name with a space and a first name and last name of at least 3 character each: `[A-Za-z]{3,}\ [A-Za-z]{3,}`

Comment: W3schools is a terrible resource. I suggest this one: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: Our professor wants us to not use anything but the fundementals for some reason :/

Comment: That's a good link Jan, i'll use it in the future.